# Phonegap upload not working

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, cordova-3

I am using phonegap for the first time and attempting to get a simple image uploaded to my server. I am using the js from the Full Example in the docs (http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer)

I am able to pull up the image gallery and select the image, but nothing is being uploaded to my server, and neither the success or failure callbacks are being fired.

I am not sure if it matters but I am using phonegap build and I am currently testing on iOS but this will eventually be on Android as well.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

after trying to manually run the functions through the debug console I realized that I had the file plugin but not the FileTransfer plugin installed. installing that appears to have fixed it.

The phonegap documentation is sorely lacking!